# General Programming about IF else if statements C#

Tags: c#, if-statement

Well i got this if else statement where i have 12 variables that can either be 0, 1, or 2. if its a 0 its pass, if its 1 it fails, if its a 2 its unknown.  I was wondering if anyone knows a shorter way of writing it in C#

here is what i have to write if there isn't

```
string pass = "pass";
string fail = "fail"; 
string unknown = "unknown"
if ( value == 0)
{
    test1 = pass; 
}
else if (value == 1)
{ 
    test1 = fail; 
}
else if (value == 2)
{
    test1 = unknown; 
}
if ( value1 == 0)
{
    test2 = pass; 
}
else if (value1 == 1)
{ 
    test2 = fail; 
}
else if (value1 == 2)
{
    test2 = unknown; 
}
.
.
.

if ( value12 == 0)
{
   test13 = pass;
}
```

Let me explain a little more.  I have 12 pictures on webpage, that need to be updated, depending on a database for the values.  Each picture can be only 1 of 3 options and can change depending on the database.  A pass(check mark), a fail(a red x) and an unknown (question mark). Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: What are the "rules"? If value12 passes, it will return `pass` no matter if all else are failing. Is that correct?

Comment: In this code, `value` and `value{1..11}` do not affect the final value of `test` so they could be ignored. Is that a typo?

Comment: This code makes no sense, as delnan says you could remove three quarters of it and not change a thing.

Comment: they are all different parameters.  for different objects.

Comment: @user990951: Has something changed to make you unaccept the answer from last year? Do you need more information about something?

Answer (score 6):

> Well i got this if else statement where i have 12 variables that can either be 0 1 or 2.

Any time you have *several variables* which you want to be able to treat in a similar way, you should use a collection for them, e.g. an array or a `List<T>`. If you don't already *have* a collection for them, you can create one:

```
int[] values = { value0, value, value2 /* etc * };
```

... although it would be better if you could have them as a collection from the very start.

Then you can iterate over all of them. It's not really clear why in this case you're overwriting the value of `test` in each block, but having a collection of inputs ends up with a natural way of creating a collection of outputs. You can also use a switch statement or a conditional expression to make the checks simpler. For example:

```
public static string ConvertValueToLabel(int value)
{
    switch (value)
    {
        case 0: return "pass";
        case 1: return "fail";
        case 2: return "unknown";
        // Adjust this behaviour as appropriate...
        default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value");
    }
}
```

Or:

```
public static string ConvertValueToLabel(int value)
{
    // Note that this doesn't do the same range checking as the version above
    return value == 0 ? "pass"
        :  value == 1 ? "fail"
        :  "unknown";             
}
```

(Some people don't like "stacking" conditionals like this, and I probably wouldn't use it in *this* case where a switch statement is probably more sensible, but it *can* be really handy.)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a case for arrays.

```
        int[] values = { 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2 };
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            if (values[i] == 1)
            {
            }
            else if (values[i] == 2)
            {
            }
        }//for
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code there is no need to check values 0-11 cause the test variable is changed again using value12. So you can just check the last value and and skip all other.

Comment: According to the question: 'that can either be 0 1 or 2'. There is no word about -1.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a for loop which checks each variable.  Or, at the very least, write the check as a function which can be referenced with each variable.  Do the former if the variables are in series and their names can be determined sequentially.  Do the later if the variable names are not really related to each other.

If necessary, place the variables into an array which can be looped through.